# Checking values entered in input box equals or not to a certain value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the `$value` and `$field` generated dynamically from php `$value = 'mango';` `$field='user_username'`. I now need to check if the text entered in input id `user_username` is mango or not.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text um-field " name="user_username" id="user_username" placeholder="">
```

Something like:

```
<?php
$value = 'mango';
$field = 'user_username';
<script>
    $(document).ready ( function(){
       var value = $("#<?php echo $field;?>").val();
       if(value === '<?php echo $value;?>') {
          alert('hi');
       } 
    });​
</script>
?>
```

Comment: Just ask yourself. When do I need to "_need to check if the text entered in input id user_username is mango or not_"? On page load, after user have entered a data or after click of some button? and the code that I have written does that?

Comment: first please make it clear that you want to check that value on client side or server side

Comment: Your `$(document).ready` function is written on a PHP file?

Comment: @varnit I want to check value on client side comparing with dynamically generated value.

Comment: @Syscall yes. is that a problem?

Comment: You are only evaluating the comparisons at runtime: you are not rechecking it whenever the user changes or updates the input field's value. You will need to listen to some kind of event on the input element and then perform the comparison.

Comment: @Steve It was just to know how was written the JavaScript.

Comment: Better use ajax and check what is written, aint  sure but like this someone can see value by looking  your code on client side

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to load your desired field into some js variable and then compare.

here is how it works roughly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("demo_test.php", function(data, status){
            var server_data=data;
        });
    });
});
```

then compare it with desired field

```
 $(document).ready ( function(){
       var value = $("#<?php echo $field;?>").val();
       if(value === server_data) {
          alert('hi');
       } 
    });​
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value on `blur`, because `$(document).ready()` is called at the beginning of the script. Also you have to close the PHP tag before to write JavaScript:

```
<?php
$value = 'mango';
$field = 'user_username';
?>

<input type="text" class="input-text um-field " name="user_username" id="user_username" placeholder="">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#<?php echo $field;?>").bind('blur', function(){
           var value = this.value;
           if(value === '<?php echo $value;?>') {
              alert('hi');
           }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, your script only compares the input field's value **at runtime** against a PHP variable. JavaScript does not automagically performs the comparison whenever the user updates the input field—you will have to bind an event handler to your input element, so that when triggered will re-invoke the logic to perform the check:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    var $field = $("#<?php echo $field;?>");
    var expectedFieldValue = '<?php echo $value;?>';

    $field.on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === expectedFieldValue) {
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
});​
```

Sometimes, it might be just a bit heavy-handed to use jQuery if you're performing a simple logic like this. The above code can also be rewritten in native JS that works in modern, evergreen browsers:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var fieldElement = document.getElementById('<?php echo $field;?>');
    var expectedFieldValue = '<?php echo $value;?>';

    fieldElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (fieldElement.value === expectedFieldValue) {
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
});
```